# BufferedReader input on if statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, bufferedreader, uiswitch

Can someone help me in this code. The if statement isn't run but the term is true.. (I see it n the Log) So what is the problem with this code? There are two line in the .txt file so the while is running twice.

The code:

```
String tag = null;
    String path = "/data/data/com.barnabas.vac.ballog/files";
    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(path+"/Settings.txt")));
        String line = "";
        Log.e(tag, "A");
        while((line = (br.readLine())) != null) {

            if(line.getBytes() == "RunApp: ON".getBytes())
            {
                RunApp.setChecked(true);
                Log.e(tag, "B => " + line);
            }
            else if(line.getBytes() == "Battery: ON".getBytes())
            {
                Battery.setChecked(true);
                Log.e(tag, "C => " + line);
            }
            Log.e(tag, line.getBytes() + " => " + "RunApp: ON".getBytes());
            Log.e(tag, "D => " + line);
        }
        Log.e(tag, "E");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the Log:

```
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): A
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): [B@419d1aa8 => [B@419d1bf8
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): D => RunApp: ON
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): [B@419d1f10 => [B@419d1fe8
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): D => Battery: ON
03-26 18:55:05.405: E/(25690): E
```

Comment: This is a new take on comparing strings...

Comment: you can't compare arrays like that. Arrays are objects, which are equals if they point to the same object in memory, not if they represent the same data. Java101.

Comment: What does the `==` operator do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing `byte[]` instances, arrays of bytes.  The `==` operator won't compare array contents, only to see if they're the same array object, which they aren't.

To compare array contents, use [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5b%5d,%20byte%5b%5d%29):

```
if(Arrays.equals(line.getBytes(), "RunApp: ON".getBytes()))
```

You'll need to change your other array comparisons similarly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is very helpfully! Now my code is running successfully!